# Registration form not working and storing data in Database(PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, web, content-management-system

I trying to construct a registration page with PHP/MySQL ,first time when i tried to register as a new user it worked perfectly .after sometime time ,i checked once again with registration ,that page is not processing the data to the database .
 the following code for registration page info as follows 
please help me out

```
<?php
    require_once("models/config.php");
    if(isUserLoggedIn()) { header("Location: index.php"); die(); }
?>


<?php
    //Forms posted
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        $errors = array();
        $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
        $confirm_pass = trim($_POST["passwordc"]);

        //Perform some validation
        //Feel free to edit / change as required

        if(minMaxRange(5,25,$username))
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_CHAR_LIMIT",array(5,25));
        }
        if(minMaxRange(8,50,$password) && minMaxRange(8,50,$confirm_pass))
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_CHAR_LIMIT",array(8,50));
        }
        else if($password != $confirm_pass)
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_MISMATCH");
        }
        if(!isValidemail($email))
        {
            $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_INVALID_EMAIL");
        }
        //End data validation
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {   
            //Construct a user object
            $user = new User($username,$password,$email);

            //Checking this flag tells us whether there were any errors such as possible data duplication occured
            if(!$user->status)
            {
                if($user->username_taken) $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USERNAME_IN_USE",array($username));
                if($user->email_taken)    $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMAIL_IN_USE",array($email));       
            }
            else
            {
                //Attempt to add the user to the database, carry out finishing  tasks like emailing the user (if required)
                if(!$user->userPieAddUser())
                {
                    if($user->mail_failure) $errors[] = lang("MAIL_ERROR");
                    if($user->sql_failure)  $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
                }
            }
    }
    if(count($errors) == 0) 
    {
        if($emailActivation)
        {
            $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE2");
        }
        else {
            $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE1");
        }
    }
}
?>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Registration | <?php echo $websiteName; ?> </title>
    <?php require_once("head_inc.php"); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-ish">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id="success">
                <p><?php echo $message ?></p>
            </div>
            <div id="regbox">
                <form name="newUser" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
                <p>
                    <label>Username:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="username" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Re-type Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label>Email:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" />
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="new" id="newfeedform"       value="Register" />
        </div>  
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p style="margin-top:30px; text-align:center;">
        <a href="login.php">Login</a> /  <a href="forgot-password.php">Forgot Password?</a> / <a href="<?php echo $websiteUrl;  ?>">Home Page</a>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you getting some errors?

Comment: i am not getting any errors,but when i click submit button ,it reloads the same registration page and no values are submitted to database/ the form is not processed to next step .help me thanks in advance

Comment: ,So show me your insert query

Comment: this very same code worked perfectly few hours back,i didn't even change anything ..but it is not working now

Comment: ,So without insert query how do you expect values to be entered into database??check properly .You may have deleted by mistake

Comment: the following tables are used in my database ,                    users -it consist of signup columns which i see in my phpmyadmin ,userpie_sessions ,projectexp1_users --this is the place i see registered users(1 registered user) ...can you please help me out with the sql query

Comment: ,look ,I have given you the abstract of your answer..Change table name,column name and syntax accordingly

Comment: thank you for helping me out ...in the above code .in which place i need to pass the query .

Comment: after conform password

Comment: i tried the way you said ,but the sql query is showing up on the html registration page...do i need to use $_POST or isset or something else like condition to process it ..

Comment: follow this tutorial..it will help you to understand.http://www.9lessons.info/2011/02/php-object-oriented-programming.html

Comment: just now checked the whole ...i have a class.newuser.php ,class.user.php in one of the site folder which is used in the above code..above code you can see newuser function invoked

Comment: the class.newuser.php files in the site folder has all the sql queries ..which are passed already ..so i tried require_once("models/class.newuser.php"); in the register page ..still not working

Comment: there is a file class.newuser.php  in the site folder that has all sql values  it passes all sql queries ..and it is used in the above code as well ..so i tried require_once("models/class.newuser.php"); in the register page ..still not working..please reply me ..thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also check your connection page properly..
add these kind of queries to your regrestration page..

`mysql_query("insert into <your_table>(email,username,password) values('$email',' $username',' $password')");`

Comment: in the above code ,in which place i should place this query ..please help me out ..so that i can try ,,thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of <yourtable> put your table name,and the column values which are there in your table like(email,name,password)..

Comment: it stores the values in one place and its there is another table with registration structure (i:E)in one table i can see ,email ,username ,password and all other columns and in another table i can see registered users ..

Comment: yeah i understood ..about the query ...where to place the this query in the above code ..

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is the MySQL code?  You've done your checks for the data but that's all it does.  It is not being sent to a database.  It's only being validated.

Comment: the following tables are used in my database ,users -t consist of signup column ,userpie_sessions ,projectexp1_users --this is the place i see registered users

Comment: the class.newuser.php files in the site folder has all the sql queries ..which are passed already ..so i tried require_once("models/class.newuser.php"); in the register page ..still not working

Comment: OK.  You have the queries themselves.  You will also need the connection string in order to connect to the database.  Something that will probably have this in it.  $host = "localhost", $user = "username", $password = "password", and $db = "database name".  You have to make the connection first, then you can send/build the queries.

Comment: already it was connected to my database through config.php $dbtype = "mysql"; 
 $db_host = "localhost";
 $db_user = "project_proexp";
 $db_pass = "proexp";
 $db_name = "project_projectexp1";
 $db_port = "";
 $db_table_prefix = "projectexp1_";

Comment: There is still more missing code.  The code you've provided shows a PHP constructor building a User Object called $user.  3 lines later: if(!$user->status).  Well, there is no $user->status defined yet.  Is this a variable or a method?  Stuff is missing.  You didn't write this, right?